# How to extract sample titles (names) using GEOquery package?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, geo

[GEOquery](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GEOquery/inst/doc/GEOquery.pdf) is a great R package to retrieve and analyze the Gene Expression data stored in [NCBI Gene Expression Omnibus (GEO) database](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/). I have used the following code provided from [GEO2R](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/geo2r/) service of GEO database (that generates the initial R script to analyze your desired data automatically) to extract some GEO series of experiments:

```
gset <- getGEO("GSE10246", GSEMatrix =TRUE)
if (length(gset) > 1) idx <- grep("GPL1261", attr(gset, "names")) else idx <- 1
    gset <- gset[[idx]]
gset # displays a summary of the data stored in this variable
```

The problem is that I can not retrieve the sample titles from it. I have found some function `Columns()` that works on GDS datasets and returns the sample names, but not on GSE.

Please note I am not interested in sample accession IDs (i.e. GSM258609 GSM258610, etc), what I want is the sample human readable titles.

Is there any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After

```
gset <- getGEO("GSE10246", GSEMatrix =TRUE)
```

`gset` is a simple list, it's first element is an `ExpressionSet`, and the sample information are in the `phenoData` or `pData`, so maybe you're looking for

```
pData(gset[[1]])
```

See `?ExpressionSet` for more.

Comment: Wow! I had no hope that such a question would be answered here. That was really cool. Thanks for your brilliant answer.